# What is the moon zenith called?

Tags: american-english

The time of day when the sun at its zenith, relative to the observer, is called "noon."

What is the lunar equivalent?  "Moon's zenith" sounds so clunky.

Comment: You could call it _high moon_ :-)

Comment: Hah, clever!  Post that as an answer!

Comment: Surely it's 'midnight' -- really as close to 12am as noon is to 12pm.

Comment: @JAM Nope. Midnight tracks the sun, not the moon. The moon is only occasionally opposite the sun.

Comment: @ghoppe I did not know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Zenith](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zenith)*, in its sense  “(astronomy) The highest point in the sky reached by a celestial body”, actually is quite suitable for the purpose.  In some sentences, *lunar zenith* may read slightly better than *moon's zenith*.

A term that is technically correct but may be misunderstood is  *[transit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transit#Noun)*, in its sense “(astronomy) The passage of a celestial body across the observer's meridian”.  A problem with *transit* is that another sense, “The passage of a celestial body ...  across the disk of a larger celestial body” is more-commonly associated with moons and satellites than is the meridian sense , which is often associated with stars.  Thus, previously-mentioned *[culmination](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/culmination#Noun)*'s sense “(astronomy) The attainment of the highest point of altitude reached by a heavenly body; passage across the meridian; transit”  may be a better choice.

Comment: Interesting... it seems that _transit_ is indeed technically the most correct since it refers to the occurrence itself.  Whereas zenith or culmination refer to a _position_ or _altitude_ and not _the time it occurs_.  Unfortunately, it seems [transit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_transit) has more than one meaning in astronomy. However, in regular English, I agree that lunar zenith sounds best.

Comment: Believe it or not, the moon can culminate without reaching it's zenith. Reason: the moon's declination changes fairly rapidly, so the moon's elevation/altitude can continue increasing after culmination. (see http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/937/ for details)

Answer (score 3):

One can say **zenith moon** as a counterpart to *noonday sun*, although it is not nearly as common.

Note that the astronomical term *[zenith](http://www.onr.navy.mil/focus/spacesciences/resources/term.htm)* actually refers to the point directly overhead the observer, not the highest position a celestial object rises over the horizon, which would be its *culmination*.

Comment: If you ask google to "define zenith" https://www.google.com/search?q=define+zenith it gives "the highest point reached by a celestial or other object" as the first definition and yours as the 2nd definition. Even as an (amateur) astronomer, I've used zenith to mean highest point, not overhead.